# Xcode 6 - iOS Simulator - take screenshot from command line

Tags: ios-simulator, screenshot, xcode6.1, xcode-instruments

In Xcode 6 Apple added simctl which allows to do a lot with the iOS simulator, but there is no option to take screenshots.
There are 2 alternatives, less comfortable:

1. Using instruments and *.js scripts - UIAutomation.
2. Using osascript as mentioned in: http://jehiah.cz/a/iphone-simulator-screenshot.

Looking for a simple way like **xcrun simctl screenshot**

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, this is not exposed via CoreSimulator.  The only way you can get the screenshot is by interacting with iOS Simulator.app.  Please file a bug report requesting this feature at http://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: Done: 19167042 - Allow to take screenshots via simctl/instruments

Answer (score 0):

Using OSAScript is the most direct way to do this if you don't want to completely automate your iOS application through UIAutomation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command: `xcrun simctl io booted screenshot Screenshot.png`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).